# going to vs going to be

Tags: sentence-construction, tense, future-tense, future-perfect, future-continuous

What's the difference between both the sentences:-

1. I am going to show you something.
2. I am going to be showing you something.
3. I will be showing you something.
4. I am going to send.
5. I am going to be sending.
   I believe ex 2 and 3 has the same meaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some contexts, there isn't much, if any difference, when you use the infinitive form of a verb... for example, "I love to read" and "I love reading".

Other times though, the choice can reflect different timescales. "I am driving to London" could mean you are literally in the car on your way to London, or it could refer to a future journey; however, "I'm going to be driving to London" is definitely a future event.

In your specific examples:

- "I'm going to send/show you something"

This suggests that you are about to carry out this action. It may be the very next thing you do.

- "I'm going to be sending/showing you something"

This suggests that you will be carrying out the action *soon*, but perhaps not immediately - for example, you may intend to say more about it before you do.

Comment: What about the case where I am specific about the time like ex- I am going to/going to be driving around 10 o clock. In this case what would you prefer?

Comment: @rahulsoni in that specific context - definitely "going to be driving". You've given a time, it's in the future, it isn't happening next. Also, it's a vague time - "*around* 10pm" - so you'll be very much in the process of 'driving'.